# Some iterative way to compute heading and GPS projection at the same time?

Tags: coordinate-system, gps, terrain, offset, heading

I have the following situation:

An off-road machine has a GPS antenna that is not at the center of the rear axle (this point is my path-tracking-control point). Let's say it's 3 meters from the rear axle and 2 meters from the left.

So, I should translate the GPS point to the center of the rear axle. For that, I need the current machine heading, given by delta latitude and delta longitude. So far, so good.

However, as my machine is turning, the heading of the rear axle and the heading of the GPS antenna are not the same.

For those, I'm looking for a method to, given an initial heading (GPS heading), start computing the antenna projection, and from that projection, calculate another heading (rear axle heading) until the system converges.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since the GPS antenna is fixed to the vehicle, the steady-state heading of GPS and vehicle are the same. And if you are calculating GPS Heading by Delta Lat / Delta Long, I think this will be the same as vehicle heading but maybe delayed by 1 second.  How accurate do you want heading to be?  How fast will your vehicle be turning? How fast does the rate of turn change? What speed will the vehicle be travelling at?

Comment: Hi Trams,

Thank you for the answer.

Steady-state (straight lines) is not my problem! I need an accurate heading during maneuvers.

A one-degree error could position my vehicle with an error of about 30 cm. That's not acceptable in my control.

A one-second delay at 30 km/h could lead my vehicle into an abyss.